# Python, pip install stuck on collecting "module_name"

Tags: python, numpy, pip, theano

Using freshly installed python 3.5.2 on windows 10, trying to install libraries via cmd, gives such result:

```
C:\Python35>pip install theano 
Collecting theano
C:\Python35>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
C:\Python35>pip list
pip (8.1.1)
setuptools (20.10.1)
C:\Python35>
```

The question is simple, how to make pip to install?

About trial and error. I did try to find solution, yes, and here is what does not work:

Using --no-cache-dir

pip install numpy-1.16.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl same for Theano

python -m pip install and every special combination of parameters like pip3 -vvv and so on.

manually deleted the contents of the cache directory

ran as administrator, launched cmd from python folder

reinstalled python, restarted pc, have internet connection

Comment: Any reason to have old versions of `pip` and `setuptools`? There are many, many newer versions (pip 21.3, setuptools 58.3). Upgrade them, and try again. Also, Python 3.5 reached its End Of Life a few months ago. Can you update to a newer Python, like 3.9?

Comment: Yes, the initial goal is to work with code, written for specific version with specific tools, but work gets stuck on installing required libraries.